# Why is chef complaining about candidate version here?

Tags: chef-infra

I have this snippet in a chef-solo recipe

```
package "myserver" do
  action :upgrade
  source "/tmp/myserver-12.4.0-16052.noarch.rpm"
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm
end
```

But chef says:

```
INFO: Processing package[myserver] action upgrade (cbgd::default line 16)
DEBUG: package[myserver] checking rpm status
DEBUG: package[myserver] checking install state
DEBUG: package[myserver] current version is 12.4.0-16050
DEBUG: package[myserver] no candidate version - nothing to do
INFO: Chef Run complete in 2.621177 seconds
```

I was expecting the upgrade to go through. A simple rpm -Uvh works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to use the upgrade action when you're installing a single package from a known source file. Change the action to :install. Also, Chef has a shortcut resource for rpm packages, `rpm_package, so you don't need the provider line (it uses it automatically.

```
rpm_package "myserver" do
  action :install
  source "/tmp/myserver-12.4.0-16052.noarch.rpm"
end
```

Finally, Chef's package resources use :install by default, so you don't need that either, actually.

```
rpm_package "myserver" do
  source "/tmp/myserver-12.4.0-16052.noarch.rpm"
end
```

To set the package name as a node attribute, you can do that in a cookbook's attributes/default.rb, in a role that is applied to the node, or on the node object itself (in a recipe, or editing the node object on the chef server). The reason for each location varies, but the general rule is:

- use cookbookname/attributes/default.rb for "sane defaults" that could be overridden elsewhere (role, node)
- use role attributes for setting across a lot of systems that share functionality (all webservers having a "webserver" role, for example).
- use node attributes directly for special and unique snowflakes. We don't recommend snowflakes, of course :-).

To do it in an attributes file:

```
default['myserver']['package_name'] = 'myserver-12.4.0-16052.noarch.rpm'
```

Then in the resource:

```
rpm_package "myserver" do
  source "/tmp/#{node['myserver']['package_name']}"
end
```

See the [Opscode Chef documentation](http://docs.opscode.com) for information on [Attribute Precedence](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files_attribute_precedence.html), [Attribute Files in cookbooks](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html). Roles are a [Ruby DSL, or straight JSON](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_roles_formats.html).

Comment: thanks a lot. I am new to chef. Could you also please help me with how to introduce an attribute in place of the source filename? I want to set an attribute rpmfile = output of ls -1tr /tmp/myserver* | head -n 1

Comment: set the attribute at the appropriate level node['myserver_location'] = `ls -1tr /tmp/myserver* | head -n 1 -` then in the provider where it says source set that to be source node['myserver_location']

Comment: To be clear setting it explicitly in the recipe as a node attribute is 1 of a number of ways to set an attribute this page will give more info http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes

Comment: thanks but you don't mean that assignment literally do you? I would very much like to do a shell exec in the middle of the recipe and assign the result to an attribute but am not able to figure the syntax for it. A literal assignment node['myserver_location'] = ls -1tr /tmp/myserver* | head -n 1 inside of rpm_package do results in sytax error.

Comment: thnaks for the update. Trouble is that I have an automated process that scp a new rpm file with filename containing build number over to /tmp once in a while. so i don't know the exact name of the rpm file before hand and i have to resort to the ls + head command. How do I stick its output into a chef attribute dynamically?